# Is hyphen always necessary in Joint-Stock Company?

Tags: hyphens

Is the hyphen always necessary in "Joint-Stock Company", or is it a matter of taste? May usage vary from company to company?

Ngram gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of taste, really. Sometimes, they are absolutely necessary to avoid confusion, but this is not the case here. Personally, I like hyphens and always use them if it will improve readability. Of course, if you write for a living, then you may well have style guides to follow.